# call function in isolated scope of a directive from another directive

Tags: angularjs

Simply put, I would like to access the isolate scope of a directive, from another directive.

$(element).scope() seems to return the parent scope, not the isolate scope.  The description below is a bit wordy so here's a plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/bG5JW5Ky0K3aTj8gTSsh?p=preview

The html below shows I have a directive for keydown event delegation and another directive which shows the code I would like to execute if the "DOWN" arrow key is pressed when that element is highlighted.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div id="page1" tabindex="-1" key-handler>
<a href="" id="testAnchor" class="highlight" on-down="API.setTarget('section0')">HIGHLIGHTED</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Both directives share the following test controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    // this API is injected as a service in the real code
    $scope.API = {};
    $scope.API.setTarget = function ( value ) {
    alert ( "$scope.API.setTarget " + value );
    return true;
  };                  
})
```

The "on-down" directive below is intended to be re-usable and allow the event delegator to execute the function contained in the "on-down" expression.  As a test, I call that in the link function to show that it does what I expect.

```
.directive ( 'onDown', [ function (  ) {

return {

    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        'action': '&onDown'
    },

    link: function ( scope, element, attr ) {           
        // test call when the directive is created to show that it works
        scope.action ( );           
    }
}
}])
```

However, when I try to access the isolate scope from another directive so that I can execute that code, the parent scope is returned instead.

```
.directive ( 'keyHandler', [

function ( ) {

    return {

              restrict: 'A',                    
              scope: {},

        link: function ( $scope, $element, $attr ) {

            $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                $element.unbind ( 'keydown' );
            });

            $element.bind ( 'keydown', function ( event ) {

                e = event || window.event;

                if ( e.stopPropagation ) e.stopPropagation ( );
                if ( e.preventDefault ) e.preventDefault ( );

                var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

                var keyCode = e.keyCode;

                // find all highlighted elements
                var highlightedEl = $('.highlight')[0];
                alert ( "highlightedEl " + $(highlightedEl).attr('id'));

                switch ( keyCode ) {

                case 40:
                  alert ( "down key pressed");
                              var downHandler = $(highlightedEl).attr('on-down');
                              if ( downHandler ) {
                                alert ( "found down handler");
                                  // trigger the function in the highlighted elements isolated scope
                                  // NOTE: targetScope seems to point to the controller scope rather than the highlighted elements isolated scope
                                  var targetScope = $(highlightedEl).scope();
                                  targetScope.action();
                              }
                  break;
                }
            });

          // give focus to this element so it receives all key events
          $scope.$evalAsync ( function ( ) {
            $element[0].focus();                        
          });               
        }
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: I've just discovered isolateScope() which appears to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

the best way that I know to resolve this issue is to use a controller to share information between the directives.

You create a directive that contains a controller that has a method you can use to pass in your data. You then create your other directives that use Require: for the main directive, and link: in the child directives to connect to and call the method on the "parent" directive...

```
app
  .directive('parentDirective', function(){
     return { 
              restrict: 'E', 
              replace: true,
              template: "<button ng-click='doSomething()'>Do something</button>",
              controller: function($scope) {
                   var somethingsToDo = ['something'];
                   $scope.doSomething = function() {
                          alert(somethingToDo.join());
                   }
                   this.addSomethingToDo = function(somethingToDo) {
                       somethingsToDo.push(somethingToDo);
                   }
             }
       };
  })
  .directive('nothingToDo', function() {
       return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'parentDirective',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                controller.addSomethingToDo('Nothing');
                }
              }
         }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's effectively what I'm doing.  

scope.action() gets mapped to API.setTarget() which is set in the controller.

Calling element.isolateScope() instead of element.scope() seems to give me the correct scope I need to call scope.action() in the directive, which maps to API.setTarget() in the parent controller.